# How to get current job on runner in Gitlab

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-api

Is possible to get or track what current job is running at specific runner?

For example. I have many projects and I want to tracking a `runner_id=123`. gitlab_api has api `[url]/api/v4/runners/[runner_id]` to get details of the runner=123. But the result doesn't show what I expect what job_id is now current working. so is it possible to get or tracking like this.

Answer (score 5):

Based on [official documents of Runners API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/runners.html#list-runners-jobs):

> List jobs that are being processed or were processed by specified
>   Runner.
>
> ```
> GET /runners/:id/jobs
> ```

Using query parameter `status=running` will get list of running jobs of the specified runner.

```
GET [url]/api/v4/runners/[runner_id]/jobs?status=running
```

Comment: Thank for your answer. The API supports up to version 10.3 that it's too high for me.

Comment: get 403 if I query jobs like this from project/group runners as maintainer.

Answer (score 1):

Beside the API, [GitLab 15.9](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/02/22/gitlab-15-9-released/#new-jobs-tab-in-group-runners-page) (February 2023) offers a new option:

> ### New jobs tab in group runners page
>
> To create a consistent runner experience across admin, group, and project views, the group runners details view now includes a list of past and current jobs that the runner runs.
>
> Among other details, you can see the job duration, as well as how much time each job was in queue before it was picked up by the runner.
>
> Having an overview of the
> queued duration can help you further analyze the runner’s queue performance.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/15_9/group-runners-job-statistics.png -- New jobs tab in group runners page]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/runners_scope.html#group-runners) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/361649).